# This code is not giving the value of the new sorted list . Can someone tell me the error in this code?

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I am making a class for sorting algorithms . But there seems to be some error which is giving the value of my sorted linked list as None. I cannot identify the missing piece of the code. Please help.

```
#Bubble sort algorithm

class Sort:
        def Bubble(self,llister):
            for i in range(len(llister)-1,0,-1):
                for j in range(i):
                    if llister[j]>llister[j+1]:
                        llister[j],llister[j+1]= llister[j+1],llister[j]

if __name__=='__main__':
    obj = Sort()
    llist = [2,5,3,15,10,13,1]

    print("The list before bubble sort : " ,llist)
    ans = obj.Bubble(llist)
    print("The list after bubble sort  :" ,ans)
```

Comment: You don't do return? I mean Bubble does not return anything so yes ans is None. I don't know if your implementation is correct (i don't read this part).

Comment: you need to return the sorted list at the end of the `Bubble` function.

Comment: Or, given that your method mutates the list in-place, simply print(llist) afterwards; returning None is the convention for mutation.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately Python doesn't do any type checking. Your `bubble` function doesn't contain a `return` statement; it therefore returns `None` by default. `ans` is therefore `None` and `None` is what is printed.

In order to avoid returning `None`, return a result explicitly instead e.g. `return 'Some'`.